# wmic diskdrive get serialnumber -> invalid xml output

Tags: wmi, serial-number, wmic

I want to read the name and the serial number of my hard drives.

I stumbled upon `wmic` but I'm having troubles. I guess these two commands should do the trick, but I only get the message:

```
Invalid Xml-Content. //(Translated)

wmic path win32_physicalmedia get serialnumber
```

or

```
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber
```

I tried the following as well:

```
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber /FORMAT:list
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber /FORMAT:xml.xsl
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber > c:\test.txt
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks JPBlanc, via the `/?` command I've found out that `SerialNumber` doesn't even exist. I now use

```
WMIC /output:"c:\hdds.txt" DISKDRIVE GET PNPDeviceID,Name /Format:CSV
```

which gives the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just making a mistake usin WMIC command line, `WMIC DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber /Format /?`  gives you keywords:

```
CSV
HFORM
HTABLE
LIST
MOF
RAWXML
TABLE
VALUE
XML
htable-sortby
htable-sortby.xsl
texttablewsys
texttablewsys.xsl
wmiclimofformat
wmiclimofformat.xsl
wmiclitableformat
wmiclitableformat.xsl
wmiclitableformatnosys
wmiclitableformatnosys.xsl
wmiclivalueformat
wmiclivalueformat.xsl
```

you can try :

```
WMIC /output:"c:\temp\serial1.xml" DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber /Format:RAWXML
```

You can replace `RAWXML` by one of the others formats.

Comment: soo `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` produces the output that i need, but i have 6 different drives and it doesnt tell me which serial number belongs to which drive ??

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look to the model `WMIC  DISKDRIVE GET Name,SerialNumber,model`

Comment: i figured out how to get the info i needed with HWinfo, but if i need to in the future

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error on Windows 7 x86 Pro (where querying the serial number [should be possible](https://superuser.com/questions/708146/how-to-get-the-hard-drive-serial-number#answer-708150)) when an external drive was connected.

This is how I fixed it:

1. Get the ID of each drive: `wmic diskdrive get deviceid /format:list`
2. Parse the output and get the first ID. In my case this was
   `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0`
3. Escape the backslashes so that the ID is `\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0`
4. Get the serial number of the drive using its escaped ID:

   `wmic diskdrive where deviceid='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get
   serialnumber /format:list`
5. Repeat steps 2 - 4 until you have the serial numbers of all drives

---

Edit: The above doesn't work on my copy of Windows XP x86 Pro.

This does:

```
wmic path win32_physicalmedia where tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber /format:list
```

Answer (score 3):

this issue occurs because the XML parser treats the control characters that are included in the serial number of some drives as invalid.

Comment: Indeed. There is a hotfix available to patch WMIC to fix this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2664203